# When using AJAX, unable to split string and treat it as an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to use AJAX to receive updates from a database without needing to reload the page. I've had very minimal problems thus far, however, I finally hit one. When retrieving information from a database, I have it convert all possible rows to an array. From there, I encode that array back to Javascript using `$test1 = json_encode($array)`. In this same PHP function, I'm doing this to multiple pieces, converting those encoded arrays to a string by doing `echo $test1."#".$test2."#".$test3`. In Javascript, I split that string by the hashtag, and then grab the information of an array by doing something like `test1 = array[1]`. When doing that, I can retrieve that array entry as a string even though it's in the fashion of a Javascript array. Any ideas on how I can make it treat that string, which is setup like an array, as an array? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would be better off to add all of the data to 1 array and json encode the whole array in one go to pass it back to the javascript code.

Comment: @NigelRen There's a problem with that solution. I'll have multiple arrays in one, all which include different information. That's not a viable solution.

Comment: You could add each data under it's own key, something like {data1: [], data2: []...` then your javascript can pick out each part as it needs it.

Comment: @NigelRen Even when doing something like that, it still won't help. I've tried just parsing the one array to it, and it does the exact same thing. When doing that, this is how it `console.log()`'s the array: https://i.gyazo.com/86cc6c052ff7e88234b6c87602bfb2ca.png

It should look like: https://i.gyazo.com/db5e2cc29913f3e7f315955930d467a2.png

Comment: It should work if you put everything in one big, nested array and only call `json_encode()` at the end.

Comment: If you call `JSON.parse()` in the first result you'll get the second.

Comment: @Barmar That was the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving the information from the AJAX response, you need to make it a Javascript Object. Convert the response to an object by doing `JSON.parse(response)` to get it to work